# FancyHDR Problem

Tags: fancyhdr

I'm having a hard time with fancyhdr package in overleaf. My goal is make a header where the `\subsection` apper on the top left side of odd pages. In even pages, i want the the `\section` to appear on the top right side (see images, which aren't mine).[image: picture1][image: picture2]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\fancyhf{}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}     
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}     
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}     
\fancyhead[OR,EL]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section{Section name} \newpage

\subsection{Subsection name}
firstpage \newpage

second page \newpage
... next page 
%\input{sections/1introduction.tex}
\end{document}
```

If you notice, i put % in the front of `\input{sections/1introduction.tex}` because wheter i let this line to compile, only the `\section`  name apper in the header. Any leads to solve this problem? If it might help, i divide my document in sections which i input them in the same way that is showed above.

Answer (score 1):

[Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! If you just swap the `\rightmark` and `\leftmark`, you will get the name of the subsection on top left of odd pages and the name of the section on the top right of even pages.

```
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}     
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[OR,EL]{\thepage}
```

To make it more like the style you have in the picture, you can add `\textit` before the commands, like `\textit{\leftmark}` in the first line.